# Append angular Directives : $compile not enough when using DOM elements yet to be created

Tags: html, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive, append

My problem is the following:

1. Using directive to simplify the HTML code works. Using link, you can even use directives that work on themselves and are able to work on the newly generated DOM elements!
2. However, when you try to append this directive instead of just typing in the HTML, it does not work!
3. Even if `$compile` allows you to interpret angular in your directive, when `$compile` is run, the DOM elements aren't created yet. Therefore, any directive that would work when typed in HTML would not work with `$compile`.

And since a simple example is best:

```js
var testApp = angular.module('testApp',[]);

testApp.controller('loadCtrl', ['$scope', '$compile', function($scope, $compile){
  var divElement = angular.element(document.querySelector("#include"));
  var appendHtml = $compile('<test></test>')($scope);
  divElement.append(appendHtml);
}]);

testApp.directive('test', function(){
  return{
     restrict: 'E',
     template: '<div id="test" ng-controller="testCtrl">Test Div</br>'+
               '{{angularloads}}</div>'
  };
});

testApp.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  test = function(){
    angular.element(document.querySelector('#test')).append('<div id="never">Success !</div>');
    return "$compile works... and yet, you will never see the 'Success !' ...";
  };
  $scope.angularloads = test();//defines by test to show that test() does run !
  
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="mybody" ng-app="testApp">
  Using append :
  <div id="include" ng-controller="loadCtrl">
  </div>
</div>
```

If you try in the snippet to type `<test></test>` in the HTML code, you can check what would be great to get!

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Comment: Your headed down the right path buy manipulating the DOM using a directive but then getting off course by adding the directive to the DOM in a controller.  Directives are the place for DOM manipulation ... stick with that.

Comment: If you want to cut down on HTML, I'd suggest looking into creating a component based application that is supported in the later releases of angular 1.x.  Read this https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component